# Streaming more than one video at a time

Tags: chromecast

I want to stream through Google Chrome
and Google Cast more than one video at a time.

For example, I selected 3 videos and send them to chromecast using Chrome Browser.

Any Suggestion on How to do this?

Comment: I'm trying enjoycast that allows you to create playlists even with content remotely ... it seems to work!

Comment: Do you want to stream the 3 videos consecutively (in a media queue), or do you want to see all 3 videos playing simultaneously, side by side?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using Cast SDK, you can form a queue of media (video or audio, not images) and load the queue and have them be played one after the other. You can even manipulate the queue (reshuffle, go next/previous, etc). The APIs to create and manage a queue is available in all three sender platforms.